# CSS Background Property - Shorthand vs Long form

Tags: css, background, semantics, background-color, shorthand

As I understand it, when you use the shorthand property `background`, the browser first sets all background properties to their default values and then puts in the values that you're declaring. Is it then better to use `background-color:white`; instead of `background:white`? Does this change when you are putting in more values such as background position or background image? Or is it always best to declare attributes individually?

I'm thinking that there must be some sort of tipping point where the savings in bytes balance the processing time gained by specifying attributes individually. However, I could be completely wrong - that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hear you about best practices, but as mentioned the differences in processing and even load time are negligible. There is no best practice for when to use these rules, aside from what makes sense in your stylesheet. The real difference is that they effect inherited properties differently. Setting `background-color: white;` will only overwrite the `background-color` rule (whether or not it was originally set with `background` or `background-color`) but `background` will overwrite the any/all `background` rules set, thus potentially killing background images and associated `background-repeat`, etc. Here's an example:

```
.box {
    background: url(star.png); // set with just background instead of background-image
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.box2 {
    background: green;
}
```

With HTML like:

```
<div class="box1 box"></div>
<div class="box2 box"></div>
```

.box1 will show the star.png image (with a blue background if the image is transparent), while .box2 will only show a green background, no image. The best practices lesson with these two rules is to evaluate CSS authoring and inheritance in general — not rendering performance. That in mind, it's generally best to apply `background` to the most general/abstracted rule of an element, and then overwrite properties on more specific instances, using classes or IDs, with `background-color`, `background-image`, etc.

Comment: What is your advice for lone elements then? Say you only have one box element and you want the background color to be blue?

Comment: I'd say `background-color`. This makes it clearer and a little more "future proof". (ie. if someone creates a rule, later on, that adds a indirectly adds a `background-image` to you element, your `background-color` rule won't interfere. Generally, the whole point of the shorthands is to be just that: A way to write multiple rules together, in a shorter/quicker format.

Answer (score 2):

The processing time of your CSS should be neglectable. If you're restraining from using them just because of that, well, don't restrain yourself anymore.

When using just a color, `background: color` and `background-color: color` should give the same result.

At then end it boils down to if you prefer shorthands to individual declarations. Usually, shorthands will use sensible defaults values, so it's all right. I usually don't remember the correct order for them (especially the `font` shorthand), but other than that I think they're fairly okay.

You might be using much more shorthand properties than you expect, anyways. For instance, `margin` and `padding` are the shorthands of their `-top`, `-right`, `-bottom` and `-left` components, and `border` is the shorthand for `border-width`, `border-color` and `border-style`, which are all shorthands for their `border-[direction]-[attribute]` properties. By using `border` instead of all the non-shorthand properties, you're saving like 11 lines.

Comment: I know it's absolutely negligible but I'm very interested in best-practices even if it doesn't make a difference - it's still cool to know you're doing it right.

Comment: The question came up because I was refactoring one of my sites and I started replacing all the separate background-color, background-position properties with background, and then I asked myself, it this right? Or rather, is this the best way to do it.

Comment: @Radu: yes, it is. CSS is simple enough that I don't know if it has any "supported" bad practice (stuff the language lets you do but shouldn't).

Comment: Good point on the border, margin and padding attributes, hadn't thought of that.